# Building Mosquitto on Intel Edison can't find websockets library

Tags: mosquitto, libwebsockets, intel-edison

I have successfully built libwebsockets based on instructions found in the [README](http://git.libwebsockets.org/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/tree/README.build.md). When I try to build mosquitto 1.4.2 (based on instructions found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/02/20/building-and-running-mosquitto-mqtt-on-intel-edison)) with websockets enabled, I get the following error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-poky-linux/4.8.2/../../../../i586-poky-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lwebsockets
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problematic line is `BROKER_LIBS:=$(BROKER_LIBS) -lwebsockets`, in `config.mk`. I've tried both of the following, giving it the full path to the `.so` file:

```
BROKER_LIBS:=$(BROKER_LIBS) -l~/libwebsockets/build/lib/libwebsockets.so
BROKER_LIBS:=$(BROKER_LIBS) -l/home/root/libwebsockets/build/lib/libwebsockets.so
```

I'm working on an Intel Edison.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following link you have to use a released version of libwebsockets. Otherwise the Mosquitto compiling would fail.

http://mosquitto.org/2015/05/mosquitto-and-current-unreleased-libwebsockets-branch/